# Recycling Center in German?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

How do you say "Recycling Center" in German?

I am going to the Recycling Center to recycle soda cans.

> Ich fahre ins ***Recyclingzentrum*** um Sodakannen zu recyceln.

Is "Recyclingzentrum" the right word here in this context ? Because I saw another translation for this word and it was very long.

Comment: Also, beverage cans are called [`Getränkedosen`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getr%C3%A4nkedose) in German, not *Sodakannen*. ;)

Comment: To my understanding of German we're not the one doing the recycling. The company does it. What we do is "Müll trennen" and in case of returning cans... well... what we do is "abgeben/wegbringen/zurückgeben"... we do not do the recycling. Also, we return our stuff at the grocery store and there are no recycling centers for cans or stuff. At least not that I know of. For bigger stuff like washing machines or fridges.. those are brought to the Recyclinghof.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33, where on earth do you ever come up with these apparently, but not quite, German phrases? Who would ever use "Sodakannen"? No German native speaker would, I can assure you!! If you translate that stuff yourself, please stop. If you get these phrases from another party, please burn their materials and never visit their web sites again. It's pure rubbish.

Comment: In Österreich gibt es das "Altstoffsammelzentrum"

Comment: With reference to the comment of @teylyn: Don't stop translating, but try another concept. For instance, take the pons dictionary and look up [can](http://de.pons.eu/übersetzung?q=can&l=deen&in=&lf=en). They categorize words. Look for 'sealed container' (your context). You see possible translations are "Dose" and "Büchse" and there's one example given for "beer/drink can" which is "Bier-/Getränkedose". And hey, you already got the word which was suggested by Lars Beck in another comment. PS: "recycling center" would be "Wertstoffsammelstelle" regaring to PONS. Close to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those places, at least those run by the administration, are called

- **Wertstoffhof** (der) or
- **Recyclinghof** (der)

See [„Recyclinghof“ at Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recyclinghof).

The preposition to use is *zu dem*, most often contracted to *zum*.

Also we have a very [complex recycling system in Germany (Wikipedia)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abfallwirtschaft), besides those yards. Especially the section *Siehe auch* is interesting to get an overview of how it works.

Comment: So it's not "Recyclingzentrum" in this context?

Comment: I've never once heard "Recyclingzentrum" in my life, and while it's morphologically sound and the meaning can be guessed, it is not guaranteed to be guessed correctly, much less pictured. The key to translation is not just mechanically translating a word, but checking if the concept behind it is familiar to the target audience. And no German will take his cans to a Wertstoffhof, which are far and few between and where no money changes hands. What every German will do instead is take the cans to the nearest supermarket, and get back a whopping 25 cent deposit per can.

Comment: Kann man sagen "Ich bringe Getränkdose in den Werkstoffhof weg"?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 No, for two reasons.
Firstly: You don't bring cans there. Those go into the so called "Gelber Sack"
Secondly: It would be "Ich bringe die Getränkedose(/meinen alten Fernseher) zum Wertstoffhof". Your intention to get rid of it there is so strongly implied that you don't need to mention it.
If you were to bring something there, that doesn't naturally go there, like let's say our mother in law, then you should add a cause.